# Uso do while dentro do if

Tags: c, while

Tenho que ler infinitas médias de alunos e se elas forem maiores ou iguais a 7  o aluno está aprovado , caso não , ele esta reprovado , e caso eu digite -1 o programa para e emite uma mensagem de finalização.

Estou tentando dificuldade em fazer esse programa e também queria adicionar algo que diga quando o usuário digite algo que não esteja entre 0 e 10 (que são as possíveis notas do alunos) , só que não estou conseguindo.

```
    printf("Digite a media final do aluno");
    scanf("%d",&media);

    if(media>=0 && media<=10)

    while(media!=-1)
    {
    if(media>=7)
    printf(" APROVADO! \n");
    printf("Media do proximo aluno: \n");
    scanf("%d",&media);
    else {
    printf(" REPROVADO! \n");
    printf("Media do proximo aluno: \n");
    scanf("%d",&media);}

    }
    printf("Fim do programa! \n"); // quando eu digito -1

    else
    printf("Voce digitou numero invalido ");

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
```

Comment: esta faltando um %d no primeiro scanf esta apenas o d

Comment: ah sim , nem percebi mas acho que não era só esse erro rsrs

Comment: De fato tinham mais algumas coisinhas, mas foi o que enxerguei logo de cara haha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagino que seja isto que quer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int media = 0;
    while (media != -1)  {
        printf("Digite a media do final aluno: \n");
        scanf("%d", &media);
        if (media < -1 || media > 10) {
            printf("Voce digitou numero invalido ");
            continue;
        }
        printf(media >= 7 ? "APROVADO!\n" : "REPROVADO!\n");
    }
    printf("Fim do programa! \n"); // quando eu digito -1
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/dDzuJD). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/vleowvhk-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/ValidationAndExit.c).

Olha como ficou mais simples. Um dos motivos de ter dificuldade é porque ainda não se acostumou a caprichar na escrita. Quando você tenta fazer tudo no lugar certo, dar os espaços que precisa, não dar onde não precisa, colocar as chaves corretas, tudo direitinho fica até mais fácil visualizar. Eu nem tentei achar o erro de tão confuso que estava.

O código tinhas repetições e partes desnecessárias. A lógica é simples:

- Entra no laço em um condição que você sabe ser verdadeira
- Pede a nota
- Verifica se ela está fora dos parâmetros estabelecidos, se está fora dá uma mensagem de erro e manda reexecutar o laço sem fazer o resto com o comando `continue`
- Se manter o fluxo manda imprimir aprovado ou reprovado de acordo com a nota
- Volta ao laço
- Sai do laço quando digitar -1

Comment: Agora entendi , eu cresci  muito o programa. Obrigado!

Comment: Só outra duvida , estaria ''errado'' essa forma aqui ? :

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/6uxEaRW (melhor para ver)

Comment: Errado não é, mas tem código duplicado e é diferente do que você postou originalmente. Eu fiz baseado no que você postou.

Comment: @Maniero Usar o `? :` realmente deixa o codigo muito bonito, tenho de começar a usar!

Comment: @FábioMorais só não abuse, tem hora pra usar

Comment: @Maniero Vou lendo um pouco sobre isso, porque é instinto meu usar logo `if` `else`, obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro, para que leia infinitas notas, você tem que ler o valor de média **dentro do while**.
Segundo, teste o valor se for maior que 10 e dê uma mensagem.
Aproveite e pense como validar menores que zero mas não -1 :)

```
media = 0;
while(media!=-1)
{
    printf("Digite a media final do aluno");
    scanf("d",&media);

    // testar a media
    if (media > 10) 
    {
       printf("digite uma média entre 0 e 10");
       continue;  // volta para o começo
    }
    ... restante do código ...

}
```

Comment: Não deveria de testar a hipótese de ser menor que 0 tambem? Neste caso menor que -1

Comment: sim, por isso deixei na resposta *"Aproveite e pense como validar menores que zero mas não -1"*, se resolver tudo não tem graça ;)

Comment: Ah ok, estava a ler os codigos apenas

Answer (score 1):

Para esse algoritmo ter laços infinitos até que que uma condição não seja atendida (Ex: `while(media != -1))` você precisar introduzir uma estrutura de repetição.

Veja:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){

float media = 0;

while(media != -1)){

    system("cls");
    printf("Digite a media do aluno:");
    scanf("%f",&media);

    if(media < -1 || media > 10){
        printf("Valor invalido!\n");
        system("PAUSE");
    }
    else if(media >= 7 && media <= 10){
        printf("Aluno aprovado!\n");
        system("PAUSE");
    }
    else if(media >= 0 && media < 7){
        printf("Aluno reprovado!\n");
        system("PAUSE");
    }

 } 

 return 0;
}
```

Existem outras formas de parar um laço de repetição, como exemplo a função `feof()`, no seu caso não seria necessário, mas não deixa de ser uma boa opção em situações onde não é possivel ou recomendado usar valores inteiros para sair de um laço.